# Why is (a | b ) equivalent to a - (a & b) + b?

Tags: oracle, binary, computer-science, theory, proofs

I was looking for a way to do a BITOR() with an Oracle database and came across a suggestion to just use BITAND() instead, replacing BITOR(a,b) with a + b - BITAND(a,b).

I tested it by hand a few times and verified it seems to work for all binary numbers I could think of, but I can't think out quick mathematical proof of why this is correct.
Could somebody enlighten me?

Comment: "All binary numbers I could think of" - beut :)  Nice question Captain.

Comment: Why does Oracle have a `BITAND()` but no `BITOR()`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A & B is the set of bits that are on in both A and B.  A - (A & B) leaves you with all those bits that are only on in A.  Add B to that, and you get all the bits that are on in A or those that are on in B.

Simple addition of A and B won't work because of carrying where both have a 1 bit.  By removing the bits common to A and B first, we know that (A-(A&B)) will have no bits in common with B, so adding them together is guaranteed not to produce a carry.

Comment: Have you written a book? It'll would probably take them a chapter to explain this. Thanks!

Comment: That's a great answer, exactly what I was looking for and easy to understand.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: it works just as well evaluated as (a + b) - (a & b), because addition is commutative.

Comment: @JustJeff: It works, but I wouldn't say that it is simply becuase "addition is commutative", since it doesn't really make it clear why it works. It works because subtraction of `a & b` correctly reverts the "destructive" effects of the carry.

Comment: @AndreyT: mine was not a 'why it works' comment. I didn't say it works b/c of commutativity; I said that b/c of commutativity, the non-obvious arrangement of (a+b)-(a&b) also evaluates to a|b.

Answer (score 23):

Imagine you have two binary numbers: `a` and `b`. And let's say that these number never have 1 in the same bit at the same time, i.e. if `a` has 1 in some bit, the `b` always has 0 in the corresponding bit. And in other direction, if `b` has 1 in some bit, then `a` always has 0 in that bit. For example

```
a = 00100011
b = 11000100
```

This would be an example of `a` and `b` satisfying the above condition. In this case it is easy to see that `a | b` would be exactly the same as `a + b`.

```
a | b = 11100111
a + b = 11100111
```

Let's now take two numbers that violate our condition, i.e. two numbers have at least one 1 in some common bit

```
a = 00100111
b = 11000100
```

Is `a | b` the same as `a + b` in this case? No

```
a | b = 11100111
a + b = 11101011
```

Why are they different? They are different because when we `+` the bit that has 1 in both numbers, we produce so called *carry*: the resultant bit is 0, and 1 is carried to the next bit to the left: `1 + 1 = 10`. Operation `|` has no carry, so `1 | 1` is again just 1.

This means that the difference between `a | b` and `a + b` occurs when and only when the numbers have at least one 1 in common bit. When we sum two numbers with 1 in common bits, these common bits get added "twice" and produce a carry, which ruins the similarity between `a | b` and `a + b`.

Now look at `a & b`. What does `a & b` calculate? `a & b` produces the number that has 1 in all bits where both `a` and `b` have 1. In our latest example

```
a =     00100111
b =     11000100
a & b = 00000100
```

As you saw above, these are exactly the bits that make `a + b` differ from `a | b`. The 1 in `a & b` indicate all positions where carry will occur.

Now, when we do `a - (a & b)` we effectively *remove* (subtract) all "offending" bits from `a` and only such bits

```
a - (a & b) = 00100011
```

Numbers `a - (a & b)` and `b` have no common 1 bits, which means that if we add `a - (a & b)` and `b` we won't run into a carry, and, if you think about it, we should end up with the same result as if we just did `a | b`

```
a - (a & b) + b = 11100111
```

Answer (score 6):

A&B = C where any bits left set in C are those set in both A and in B.
Either A-C = D or B-C = E sets just these common bits to 0. There is no carrying effect because 1-1=0.
D+B or E+A is similar to A+B except that because we subtracted A&B previously there will be no carry due to having cleared all commonly set bits in D or E.

The net result is that A-A&B+B or B-A&B+A is equivalent to A|B.

Here's a truth table if it's still confusing:

```
 A | B | OR   A | B | &    A | B | -    A | B | + 
---+---+---- ---+---+---  ---+---+---  ---+---+---
 0 | 0 | 0    0 | 0 | 0    0 | 0 | 0    0 | 0 | 0  
 0 | 1 | 1    0 | 1 | 0    0 | 1 | 0-1  0 | 1 | 1
 1 | 0 | 1    1 | 0 | 0    1 | 0 | 1    1 | 0 | 1  
 1 | 1 | 1    1 | 1 | 1    1 | 1 | 0    1 | 1 | 1+1
```

Notice the carry rows in the + and - operations, we avoid those because A-(A&B) sets cases were both bits in A and B are 1 to 0 in A, then adding them back from B also brings in the other cases were there was a 1 in either A or B but not where both had 0, so the OR truth table and the A-(A&B)+B truth table are identical.

Another way to eyeball it is to see that A+B is almost like A|B except for the carry in the bottom row. A&B isolates that bottom row for us, A-A&B moves those isolated cased up two rows in the + table, and the (A-A&B)+B becomes equivalent to A|B.

While you could commute this to A+B-(A&B), I was afraid of a possible overflow but that was unjustified it seems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){ unsigned int a=0xC0000000, b=0xA0000000;
printf("%x %x %x %x\n",a,   b,       a|b,       a&b);
printf("%x %x %x %x\n",a+b, a-(a&b), a-(a&b)+b, a+b-(a&b)); }

c0000000 a0000000 e0000000 80000000
60000000 40000000 e0000000 e0000000
```

*Edit*: So I wrote this before there were answers, then there was some 2 hours of down time on my home connection, and I finally managed to post it, noticing only afterwards that it'd been properly answered twice.  Personally I prefer referring to a truth table to work out bitwise operations, so I'll leave it in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

[image]