# What is a good way to do bitor in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, plsql, bit, bitwise-operators

What is a good way to do bitor operation in pl/sql ?

Currently we are using

```
bitor(x,y) = x + y - bitand(x,y)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1604269/183181  as you are

Answer (score 8):

I've been happy with this emulation in the past

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bitor(x NUMBER, y NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN x - bitand(x, y) + y;
END;
```

It's the same as yours. [An explanation can be found here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_bitor_sql.htm)

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 21, there are built-in `BITOR` and `BITXOR` functions; however, they are undocumented.

```sql
SELECT a,
       b,
       BITAND(a, b),
       BITOR(a, b),
       BITXOR(a, b)
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (a, b) AS
  SELECT 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | A | B | BITAND(A,B) | BITOR(A,B) | BITXOR(A,B) |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
> | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
> | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
> | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

*Note: There are also new (and documented) [aggregation functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848) `BIT_AND_AGG`, `BIT_OR_AGG` and `BIT_XOR_AGG`.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b39c30d2f27aaae1cc89dd06ed534d92)*

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [UTL_RAW](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/UTL_RAW.html#GUID-7781BB09-A1CD-43A2-9133-056E439D9755) package. There you can find `BIT_AND`, `BIT_COMPLEMENT`, `BIT_OR` and `BIT_XOR` Function

However, first you have to convert numeric values to `RAW`, e.g. [CAST_FROM_BINARY_INTEGER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/UTL_RAW.html#GUID-261178FB-9C00-4829-82F0-C625BFB1EFB5)

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 6 AS x, 8 AS y FROM dual),
r AS (
    SELECT
        x, y,
        UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_BINARY_INTEGER(x) AS raw_x,
        UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_BINARY_INTEGER(y) AS raw_y
    FROM t),
op AS (
    SELECT
        x, y,
        raw_x, raw_y,
        UTL_RAW.BIT_AND(raw_x, raw_y) AS BIT_AND,
        UTL_RAW.BIT_OR(raw_x, raw_y) AS BIT_OR,
        UTL_RAW.BIT_XOR(raw_x, raw_y) AS BIT_XOR
    FROM r)
SELECT 
    UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_BINARY_INTEGER(BIT_AND),
    UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_BINARY_INTEGER(BIT_OR),
    UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_BINARY_INTEGER(BIT_XOR)
FROM op;
```